# Meteor deployed to subfolder with nginx error

Tags: nginx, meteor, iron-router

I deployed meteor app (bundle) on Amazon EC2 Ubuntu with nginx. I need to run my app on example.com/myapp.
I used:

```
export ROOT_URL='http://example.com/myapp'
```

Part of my nginx:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name: example.com;

    location /myapp {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    ...
```

But I'm getting errors:

```
Exception in defer callback: Error: Oh no! No route found for path: "/myapp/"
```

and:

```
GET http://example.com/cfs/servertime 404 (Not Found)
GET http://example.com/font/myfont 404 (Not Found)
```

How to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

The thing is with nginx, it can help you solve the server side routing bit of it, but the it can't help with the client side routing (since the browser computes this bit).

There's no alternative to it other than prefixing your client side routes to `/myapp/`.

You can leave your server side routes as-is since nginx will route them for you.

Comment: Thank you.
Is it possible to prefixing my client side routes in Meteor (Iron Route) to /myapp/ automaticaly not by adding "myapp/" to each route?
Is it possible nginx to send to meteor request like "example.com/path" instead of "example.com/myapp/path"?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in iron-router you can use a variable for the prefix path. See my usage here https://github.com/c316/give/blob/master/both/router/routes.js. Basically you just declare the variable in the data portion of the route and then use :variableName in the path.

Comment: Thanks Josh!
I need to declare this variable in each route? Why it's better then just adding "myapp/" to each route?
And does this solution solves the problem of client side routes from public folder?

Comment: You could just add the myapp/ in the route folder, but I like using the variable in case I have a development app that I run in a different subfolder. This way I don't have to change every instance of that name, just run a different name inside my settings.json file. Client side routing to a public folder just need to use the same process. So if I am linking to an image I do this Meteor.settings.root + '/images/check_image.png'. If you just prepend /myapp to the path, you'll get into the public directory. Is that what you were asking about?

Comment: Yeah! Thank you so much. But your answer gives more questions )
1. May I define root var just once not in every route?
2. What about Router.go('path')? How to achieve Router.go(':root/path')?
3. In my templates I use `<a href="{{pathFor 'home'}}"></a>`. How to add root path there?
4. I use FS.Store.FileSystem for FS.Collection store. How to add root path there?

Sorry if these questions are stupid, but all this not obviosly for me yet.

Comment: And it seems that Meteor object doesn't have settings property: I got _Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'root' of undefined_ (meteor 9.3.0)